# What is a good configuration file tool for C#

Tags: .net, configuration-files

I'm writing a new C# application which will make heavy use of a configuration file.  My requirements are:

1. Human readable
2. Name value pairs
3. Hierarchical
4. [Updatable by application]

Um, to translate:  I want to define an object and a set of configuration parameters associated with that object.  The configuration parameters may be name value pairs or another object, with it's own attributes attached:

module "db" {
  host:  "db.example.com";
  encoder "zip" {
    compression: 10;
  }
}

I'm less committed to requirement 4, but do consider that I would like the application to update a setting and write it back to the configuration file.

I am aware of the following options:

1. XML.  Not sufficiently human readable.
2. INI file.  Not hierarchal
3. JSON.
4. YAML.

JSON and YAML seem worth investigating.

Advise on using these for configuration?  Any alternate tools I may want to consider?

As for persisting changes made by the application back to the config file I know that JSON and YAML can do this but can either do this WHILE saving comments which may have been in the original human edited version?

Answer (score 4):

No sense in rebuilding the wheel. Why not just use the built-in configuration API?  It uses XML, so you can edit by hand at run-time if you want to. there is a built-in editor in the IDE to edit at build-time.

[here is more from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I use custom configuration files when I need to do something like that. [Here's how I did it](http://blog.yapb.net/post/2009/09/22/Creating-your-own-Custom-Configuration-Section.aspx).

Comment: Link returns a 404 :(